# JS method to break RESTful URL into parts and return them

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I have an AngularJS web application. Application has similar functionality as [Dev HTTP Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dev-http-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm) (it sends different HTTP methods to REST resources on the project). It looks like this:

[image]

Now I would like to have a possibility to determine something about the entered url. 
Basicaly, url can be off 3 types:

1. `http://localhost:8080/REST/api/contents/` - resources collection
2. `http://localhost:8080/REST/api/contents/Q1W2E3R4T5` - single resource
3. `http://localhost:8080/REST/api/contents/Q1W2E3R4T5/questions` - child resource collection

What I want is to have a function that takes url as a parameter and returns an object with 3 properties:

- resources collection if specified, otherwise empty string
- single resource if specified, otherwise empty string
- child resource if specified, otherwise empty string

Does anyone know how to do such thing using JS or AngularJS?

Every useful answer is highly appreciated and evaluated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
function breakUrl(url){

    var start = 'http://localhost:8080/REST/api/',
        s1 = url.split(start),
        s2 = s1[1].split('/');

    return {  
        resource: s2[0] || '',
        single: s2[1] || '',
        child: s2[2] || ''
    };

}

console.log(breakUrl('http://localhost:8080/REST/api/contents'));
console.log(
       breakUrl('http://localhost:8080/REST/api/contents/Q1W2E3R4T5/questions'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BL3JL/